# Integrating $\int \sec xdx$: Why is $\ln|\text{sec}x + \text{tan}x| + C$ preferred over $\tanh^{-1}(\sin x) + C$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, soft-question, indefinite-integrals, trigonometric-integrals

I was trying to integrate $\sec^3x$ and discovered that I would have to integrate $\sec x$ in the process. I had not seen the "standard" approach and came up with my own solution, which is apparently quite different: 
$$\int \sec xdx = \int \frac{dx}{\cos x}$$ 
I substituted $u = \sin x$ so that $dx = \frac{du}{\cos x}$. Then 
$$\int \frac{dx}{\cos x} = \int \frac{du}{\cos^2x} = \int \frac{du}{1 - \sin^2x} = \int \frac{du}{1 - u^2}$$ 
The solution to this is $\tanh^{-1}u + C$. Since $u = \sin x$, this means that 
$$\int \sec xdx = \tanh^{-1}(\sin x) + C \tag{1}$$

After looking it up, I found out that the standard form of the integral is $$\int\sec x dx = \ln|\text{sec}x + \text{tan}x| + C \tag{2}$$

I couldn't find anything about the alternate form $(1)$ which is, as far as I can tell, equivalent to $(2)$. So, did I make a mistake here? If not, is there a reason to prefer the usual form $(2)$?

Comment: You might be interested in reading about the [Gudermannian function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gudermannian_function) (see [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Gudermannian.html) also). See this [8 October 2009 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sci.math/pXzKDIUD2fY) and [these notes](http://www.cs.uleth.ca/~holzmann/notes/gudermann.pdf) for connections with the integral of secant.

Comment: See also https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/questions/14631/why-do-we-state-the-antiderivative-of-sec-x-as-ln-sec-x-tan-x

Comment: No mistake, you've just come across on of the many amazing relationships that exist between our elementary (and non-elementary) functions. No one form is better or worse than the other. Depending upon the situation they each have their advantages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\tanh^{-1}(\sin x) &=\frac12\ln\left|\frac{1+\sin x}{1-\sin x}\cdot \frac{1/\cos x}{1/\cos x}\right|\\[4pt]
&=\frac12\ln\left|\frac{\sec x+\tan x}{\sec x-\tan x}\right| \\[4pt]
&=\frac12\ln\left|\frac{\sec x+\tan x}{\sec x-\tan x}\cdot\frac{\sec x+\tan x}{\sec x+\tan x}\right|\\[4pt]
&=\phantom{\frac12}\ln\left|\sec x+\tan x\right|
\end{align}$$

I believe most introductory calculus books use the equivalent form because their readers are not aware of hyperbolic trigonometric functions or their inverses.

Answer (score 0):

I was taught to calculate $\;\int (\sec x) dx\;$ via the substitution $\;u = \tan(x/2).\;$  As the other answer suggested, in math, you don't want to use a steamroller when a flyswatter will do.  Problems involving $\;\int (\sec x) dx\;$ (for example $\;\int (\sec x)^3 dx)\;$ can be solved in a straightforward (if somewhat arduous) manner without using hyperbolic functions.

The convention is to avoid advanced topics (e.g. hyperbolic functions), unless the problem requires it.